# Puppet - iterate over hash

Tags: arrays, hash, iteration, puppet, hiera

We're using puppet 3.8 (unfortunately can't move to puppet 4 yet)

I've got a hash in hiera that looks something like this:

```
hash_data:
  item1:
    field1:   'some data'
    array_data:
      - data1
      - data2
  item2:
    field1:   'other data'
    array_data:
      - data3
      - data4
```

I've put together a module with code something like:

```
class processor {
    $data = hiera_hash('hash_data', {})

    create_resources(processor::hash_entry, $data)
}

define processor::hash_entry ($field1, $array_data) {
#    .. do_something ..

# process array items
    processor::process_array { $array_data : 
        datavar = 'somevalue'
    }
}

define processor::process_array($element, $datavar) {
    # do something
}
```

this works fine as long at the array_data fields in the hash all contain unique fields. However, if I need to put non-unique data something like:

```
hash_data:
  item1:
    field1:   'some data'
    array_data:
      - data1
      - data2
  item2:
    field1:   'other data'
    array_data:
      - data3
      - data2                  ( **non-unique value **)
```

then we hit a duplicate resource. Can anyone suggest how I could process that hash?

Thanks

Comment: The outcome you want is unclear. If `data2` is defined in the YAML twice, do you want to only define `Processor::ProcessArray[data2]` once or twice? Should it be skipped if already defined, or should it be defined uniquely based also on the processor::hash_entry name?

Comment: @DominicCleal - apologies, should have been clearer.  I'd want the entries to be handled as unique instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue begins here, where `processor::process_array` is given non-unique data as its name:

```
define processor::hash_entry ($field1, $array_data) {
    processor::process_array { ${array_data}:
        # ...
```

When `processor::hash_entry` is called twice with overlapping/identical `array_data`, this generates:

```
Processor::Process_array[data1]
Processor::Process_array[data2]
Processor::Process_array[data3]
Processor::Process_array[data2]
```

which I would guess is the duplicate resource you report.

If you prefix this with unique data, i.e. the "item1"/"item2" name of the `processor::hash_entry` resources (or field1 if appropriate) then they would be unique.

Using the [stdlib prefix()](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib#prefix) function, prefix all data* entries with the hash_entry name:

```
define processor::hash_entry ($field1, $array_data) {
    $prefixed_array_data = prefix($array_data, "${title}-")
    processor::process_array { ${prefixed_array_data}:
        # ...
```

This will generate:

```
Processor::Process_array[item1-data1]
Processor::Process_array[item1-data2]
Processor::Process_array[item2-data3]
Processor::Process_array[item2-data2]
```

If you need to access the `data2` value inside `process_array` without the prefix then you can always [split](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/function.html#split) the `$title` to get the data back out.

```
define processor::process_array($element, $datavar) {
    $split_title = split($title, '-')
    $data = $split_title[1]
    # do something
}
```

Comment: We can't deploy the full stdlib for various reasons, but putting the prefix function in the module let me do what I needed!